# How to Pass Data Object to View Controller Embedded in Navigation Controller in Different Storyboard

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

My code which normally works fine for passing an object to another view controller is not working when the view controller is in a different storyboard.

My code loads the correct view controller embedded in its navigation controller but without any data. (The data object is nil in the destination VC).

Here is the code I'm trying to use;

```
UIStoryboard *sb2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondSB" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* nav = [sb2 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userNav"];
userDetail *destVC = (userDetail * )nav.topViewController;
NSLog(@"user name%@",user.name);//Logs name showing the user is not empty
destVC.user = user;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above loads a VC with no data.

I am able to pass the data object to the VC if I present the VC directly without the navigation controller.  But in that case, I lose the navigation functionality which I need.

```
UIStoryboard *sb2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondSB" bundle:nil];
userDetail *destVC = [sb2 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userDetail"];
NSLog(@"user name%@",user.name);//Logs name showing the user is not empty
destVC.user = user;
[self presentViewController:destVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What could be wrong with the above code and what code should I use.

**Edit:**

I am able to pass a regular object such as a String to the VC embedded in the nav.  Or I can pass a custom object to the VC when it is not embedded in the nav. I just can't pass a custom object such as user or I created another NSObject for testing to the VC when embedded in a nav. Perhaps this is some weird glitch when using a different storyboard.

**Edit 2**

Here is the object code for a light version of user I created in case there was something wrong with the original user object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface lightUser : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * userid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descript;

@end
```

It is a property in the VC:

```
#import "lightServer.h"
//in interface
@property (weak, nonatomic) lightUser* user;
```

The following code in ViewDidLoad does not have any effect and the user appears as nil:

```
self.user.name = @"Hello there";//
```

`po self.user.name` in debugger shows nil
`po self.user` in debuggers shows nil

Comment: At this line: `NSLog(@"user name%@",user.name);` ... what is the value of `destVC`? Is it a valid reference to the navigation controller's "root" view controller, of class `userDetail`? (side note: class names should begin with upper-case)

Comment: I just did a quick test, and it worked fine for me. Are you doing something else to your `user` object inside your `userDetail` controller?

Comment: Your first comment: when I set a break point and do po, both the nav and the destVC display visually the way the destVC is supposed to appear (with no data values).  The nav does not display as different from the destVC but rather appears identical to the destVC . I can't decode the references. P for nav gives (UINavigationController *) $20 = 0x0000000111008800 p for destVC gives (userDetail *) $21 = 0x0000000110a43a40

Comment: 2nd comment: Other than display user.name in viewdidload, I don't do anything unusual with it. There are some methods in the user object itself that combine first and last names etc. into one name. That's about it.

Comment: You're right about something going wrong with the user (custom) object. I tried sending a string and that worked.

Comment: Does not explain, however, why the custom data object can be passed directly to the VC without the nav.

Comment: Well, you need to show some more of your code. What is the structure of your custom data object? How is it being initialized in your `destVC`? Strip things down to minimum code to reproduce the issue so we can take a look at that (see [mcve]).

Comment: The object is an NSObject file and is merely declared as a property in the .h file of the VC. I was under the apparently mistaken impression that any property declared in the interface is automatically initialized. However, it appears that the property is not initialized as it is appearing as nil in viewdidload when the nav is pressented. However, it is initialized when the VC is presented without the nav. I am going to try to manually initialize it and see if that works.

Comment: I tried initing the object in viewDidLoad. This works if you have breakpoints set and go step by step. However, I think there is some sort of race condition because if I remove the breakpoints, then it no longer works (object nil when loads). So I'm at a loss. Don't know how to init property manually prior to VC loading

Comment: Actually, it seems to be typing po in the debugger that gets it to work. Otherwise, the object stays nil

Comment: Added an example project on GitHub - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure without seeing a full example of your code, but I you must be missing something...

Here is a complete example. It should be obvious what gets connected to `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` (and Storyboard IDs):

**UserObject.h**

```
//
//  UserObject.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/1/20.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UserObject : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSInteger age;

- (NSString *)name;

@end
```

**UserObject.m**

```
//
//  UserObject.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/1/20.
//

#import "UserObject.h"

@implementation UserObject

- (NSString *)name {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", _lastName, _firstName];
}

@end
```

** FirstViewController.h**

```
//
//  FirstViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/1/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

** FirstViewController.m**

```
//
//  FirstViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/1/20.
//

#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "UserDetailViewController.h"
#import "UserObject.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UserObject *aUserObject;
@property (assign, readwrite) NSInteger iAge;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize age
    _iAge = 25;

    // initialize a new UserObject
    _aUserObject = [UserObject new];

    _aUserObject.firstName = @"John";
    _aUserObject.lastName = @"Smith";
    _aUserObject.age = _iAge;

}

- (IBAction)didTap:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *sb2 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondSB" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* nav = [sb2 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"userNav"];

    UserDetailViewController *destVC = (UserDetailViewController * )nav.topViewController;

    // increment age, so it changes each time we call this method
    _iAge++;

    _aUserObject.age = _iAge;

    destVC.userObj = _aUserObject;

    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];

}

@end
```

**UserDetailViewController.h** (VC is in second storyboard)

```
//
//  UserDetailViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/31/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "UserObject.h"

@interface UserDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UserObject *userObj;

@end
```

**UserDetailViewController.m**

```
//
//  UserDetailViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 3/31/20.
//

#import "UserDetailViewController.h"

@interface UserDetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userLabel;
@end

@implementation UserDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _userLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"_useObj.firstName: %@ \n" \
                       "_userObj.lastName: %@ \n" \
                       "_userObj.age: %ld \n" \
                       "_userObj name method: %@",
                       _userObj.firstName,
                       _userObj.lastName,
                       _userObj.age,
                       [_userObj name]];

}

@end
```

In case it's not completely clear, here is a working example app: https://github.com/DonMag/DataObjectPassing